# How to determine when the WP7 SIP keyboard has been dismissed

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've noticed that when the SIP keyboard is displayed, the **OnBackKeyPress** event isn't fired when the user dismisses the keyboard via the WP7 back button.

Is there a way for me to determine when the keyboard has been dismissed via the back button?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the textbox's `KeyUp` event and then check the `PlatformKeyCode`.

```
 <TextBox Text="TextBox" Width="460" KeyUp="Textbox_KeyUp" />
```

Then, in your event handler:

```
private void Textbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     //27 is the PKC for the hardware back button
     if (e.PlatformKeyCode == 27)
     {
         //Backbutton is pressed
     }            
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I mean the WP7 back button, not the "back space" key. The hardware back button. Will your solution work in that case because the event KeyUp event isn't relevant for that hardware button surely?

Comment: `KeyUp` is used because the textbox is absorbing the back button event (so that it can be dismissed). The override you usually use is called from the page which is why it works when you do `override OnBackKeyPress`. So the code above reads from the textbox and detects when the hardware back button is pressed.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it and it doesn't work unfortunately. However Ku6opr's suggestion above works perfectly. Thanks for the suggestion :-)

Comment: Ok, sorry my mistake. Your suggestion actually also works well. And it's somewhat cleaner.

Comment: That was probably me, when I mistakenly thought it didn't work. Please edit the answer so I can upvote again as right now it's locked. Sorry about that, and thanks again.

Comment: Ah, no problem. I'll leave the answer as it, I don't mind the vote. I just thought that someone saw a mistake but didn't correct me :)

Comment: it doesn't seem to work for wp8 :(  was hoping it would.  lostFocus isn't the greatest solution for a complex scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Check for `LostFocus` event on `TextBox`. Maybe it can be suitable for you (but it also will fire when a user tap outside of `TextBox`)

Comment: Thanks, I'm not at my computer right now but I'll give that a shot as well.

Comment: Perfect, so obvious in hindsight :-) Thanks